# RadioTray error: gstplaysink

Tags: streaming, plugin

I installed RadioTray in Lubuntu 12.04 (64bit) and it can't play radio streams.
When a stream is started, it throws this notification:

> ```
> > Radio Error gstplaysink.c(1906): gen_audio_chain ():/
> > GstPlayBin2:player/GstPlaySink:playsink0
> ```

I can play all those streams from audacious and the browser itself (chrome).

I have been playing radio streams (shoutcast) for months and had been using streamtuner2 to find streams (but it has a sorting error that you cannot tell what stream will you end up listening to).

I also can watch videos with vlc and in youtube, etc.

Maybe it could be some plugins problem, but I can't find any logs.

Comment: I found [this solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055871), but @arochester 's answer is the most complete. In my specific case, installing all gstreamer-plugins (bad, ugly and ffmpeg) has solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: http://linuxlubuntu.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/radio-tray-installing.html

Comment: Thanks! I just found a short answer here: [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055871), but yours is more complete!

Comment: Please [do not answer with just a link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important information in your post; provide the link for further information.